# Need to restrict AD users - Windows Authentication in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, database, windows, authentication, restrict

I have a website which uses Windows Authentication. I need to restrict access to only a few users, who are present in a local database. How can I achieve it? Example DB has "domain\user1", only user1 should be allowed. "domain\user2" should not be allowed.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

in your controller class, you can use the **[Authorize]** attribute to restrict access.

If you use it by itself, then you restrict the entire controller to only authenticated users.

If you want specific users to access a controller, you can add parameters to the Authorize attribute, such as:

```
[Authorize(Roles ="Administrators")]
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
```

In the example above, I'm restricting the use of the homecontroller to administrators only, I can also give access only to specific users:

```
[Authorize(Users = "user1")]
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
```

You can also apply this to specific methods in your controller

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but the website is in ASP.NET (not ASP.NET MVC).